# Django Mixing Static Pages With Django Apps

Tags: php, python, django, webserver

I have a Django project that has one database-driven (i.e. normal) Django app. I have a .php webpage that I would like to include within the Django project that is a D3 visualization based on CSV files. Is it possible and kosher to include this page that includes php, JavaScript, and references to static CSV files in the Django project? If so, how would it be accomplished?

I have seen flatpages, but the Django documentation and various tutorials make it seem like that is only for simple html pages.

Answer (score 0):

Django is web framework for the python language; in order to 'serve' your project pages you'll need a `web server` to take in the requests, and a  `application server` to process your ... python code!
When you're developping locally and use the `runserver` commands, it simulates both server for you to test your project locally.

Same goes to your php, it'll need both those components to serve the page.

When you want to expose your pages to the world, you don't want to use "runserver". You could use the same web server to serve both Django pages and your Php pages, such as [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) ([example of multi config](https://serverfault.com/questions/560979/using-single-nginx-server-to-serve-proxy-php-python-and-nodejs)) or Apache ([example with a multi config](https://serverfault.com/questions/551289/how-to-have-php-and-mod-wsgi-python-app-on-the-same-domain)).
You will need to "isolate" or "match" URLs for either running your php application server or the python one.

Comment: I know how to serve a Django project and related static files. My question was centered more on how to include full static SITES next to Django apps.

Comment: Then you have your Web server, taking in request, forwarding them to your Django project, and serving the response back. Now you need to configure this webserver to respond to your specific URL or set of URLs for your static page(s). Like in the [given example with apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/551289/how-to-have-php-and-mod-wsgi-python-app-on-the-same-domain), all trafic going to /forum will be redirected to his "forum pages"

Comment: Also in your original question, you mention a PHP webpage, not a full static website, or websites. This would change everything :). The full static website will not require a change in your webserver, a php script would.

Comment: Correct, there is a php script inside my website.

Comment: Then you need to tweak your server; which one do you use (Apache/Nginx/...) ?

Comment: IIS...but I don't necessarily want to run php and Django in tandem, because I have seen that it is a bad idea. I know I could write the folder crawling code in Python, but I'm not sure how that would be implemented in Django.

Comment: You want to display PHP and Python generated content; but you do not want to "run PHP and Python"? This does not make sense. You could then first render all your "php pages" to pure html, and use those in your Django project. Otherwise you'll have to "run PHP and Python".